# Cannot able to access wp-admin page

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress website in my ubuntu server. Eg, my website url is 
xyz.com. when i'm trying to access wp-admin page it should be xyz.com/wp-admin.  But it redirect to another url like xyz.com/xyz/wp-admin

Can anyone give solution for this issue?

Comment: Did yopu change url in wp_options table?

Comment: no. I didn't change url

Comment: is it xyz.com in wp_options? I mean to say your domain

Comment: @dijofrancis Please check your htaccess file or paste your htaccess file

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress admin dashboard is `/wp-admin` from whatever directory your website is installed.

For instance, you have a website `https://dijofrancis.com` and wp is installed in the ***root*** directory then your admin url is `https://dijofrancis.com/wp-admin`

Answer (score 0):

If you paste your .htaccess file (situated at the root of your webserver directory) we could help a little more.

I once had a similar issue when I stupidly made a global redirect with a wildcard on my website.

If you say that when you access:

```
xyz.com/wp-admin
```

it redirects you to

```
xyz.com/xyz/wp-admin
```

Then it might be a permalink issue.

Re-make your permalinks from WP dashboard.

Also, you can try to use

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wps-hide-login/
```

and test from another link (if issue is permalink, maybe WPS HL will interact with wp-admin in a way that will work for some reason)